# Unable to remove app from SharePoint 2013 site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin, powershell

I've seen this problem in several places in our dev and test implementation of SharePoint 2013. Especially in sites where there has been a lot of testing where people uninstall and install apps.

The app seems to get stuck in that it's not really installed or uninstalled.

If i try to uninstall it with powershell I get the error:

> Uninstall-SPAppInstance : Another job exists for this app instance.
>   Please retry after that job is done.

The timer service is running and has been restarted.
Any ideas on how to remove the app so it can be installed properly?

Comment: did you try the uninstall script from this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ocarpen/archive/2012/08/15/scripts-to-install-update-or-uninstall-a-sharepoint-2013-app-with-powershell.aspx

Comment: Yeah we did. We ended up submitting a Microsoft ticket for this and the issue is supposed to be fixed in the May 2015 CU.

Comment: After the November 2016 CU  was released and installed in our environment we were able to retry most of the apps and get them to work. There were still some instances that didn't work and we had to have Microsoft create a script to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you.

1) Go to the AppInstallations table in the content DB.

2) Select the recode related to your app

3) Update the status to 5

4) Do IIS Reset

5) Navigate to Site content and go to the context menu of the Corrupted app

6) Click the “Remove” Link

More details:

[http://sujeewa.com/2015/06/remove-corrupted-app-from-the-farm/](http://web.archive.org/web/20160423060524/http://sujeewa.com/2015/06/remove-corrupted-app-from-the-farm)

Comment: Is the link from your own blog? If you, you should mention that to avoid deletion of the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I think this is generally a very bad practice. The content DB should not be edited or changed in any way. You are losing official support from Microsoft if you touch it, ever!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I was having problems with the Secure Store Service (I'd deleted the SSS and recreated it but forgot to generate a new key) so in particular my Access Apps were half installed but there was no REMOVE option on the app details tab. Resolution was to get the SSS working again then simply click retry on the App, the install fails but now you should have the option to remove.